# Исключить повторы в MySQL с помощью DISTINCT, отобрав при этом последний повтор?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
<? 
$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), hot_water, cold_water, pay_id 
    FROM info 
    WHERE timenow > '".$timenow."' AND status = 0
";
```

Запрос отбрасывает повторы по user_id но возвращает первый повтор, как настроить ORDER BY чтобы он последний повтор выдавал?

Comment: Для этого можно использовать конструкцию: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT * FROM info WHERE timenow > ... ORDER BY timenow DESC) `. Либо что-то типа этого: `SELECT ... FROM info WHERE (user_id, timenow) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(timenow) FROM info GROUP BY user_id)`

Comment: Переписал так: `$query = "SELECT id, user_id, hot_water, cold_water, status, datanow FROM info WHERE timenow.> '".$timenow."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";`

Comment: @АндрейФроленок пожалуйста, или оформите это как ответ, или удалите вопрос, чтобы не висел в "неотвеченных"

Answer (score 4):

Переписал так:

```
$query = "
    SELECT id, user_id, hot_water, cold_water, status, datanow 
    FROM info 
    WHERE timenow.> '".$timenow."' 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 1
";
```